# How to post some collection of <T> data to MVC action?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

```
public class Graphic
{
    ...
    ...
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int GraphicId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GraphicArtwork> GraphicArtworks { get; set; }
}

public class GraphicArtwork
{
    [Key]
    public int GraphicArtworkId { get; set; }
    public int GraphisId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} is required.")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ArtOptionText { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }
}
```

I have this two table and model.  Here I have one Graphics with Many Art Work option. I have created my Artwork Option in view using Knockout.js. now my problem is that How to post(Action method) these data so that I can insert into GraphicArtwork table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Graphic data)
{
  // "data" will contain all posted values  
}
```

Comment: I wants client side logic so that i can get this value